# $\{x\in\mathcal H:|\langle x-x_0,x_0\rangle|<(1-1/\sqrt2)\langle x_0,x_0\rangle\}$ contains at most one basis element $e_n$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a seperable Hilbert space with basis $\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$. In notes that I'm reading, it is claimed that the set $$S:=\{x\in\mathcal H:|\langle x-x_0,x_0\rangle|<(1-1/\sqrt2)\langle x_0,x_0\rangle\}$$ contains at most one of the basis elements $e_n$. Why is this the case?

Setting $\delta:=(1-1/\sqrt2)\langle x_0,x_0\rangle$, for $e_m,e_n\in S\cap\{e_j:j\in\mathbb N\}$, the triangle inequality gives $|\langle e_m-e_n,x_0\rangle|<2\delta$, but this not seem to help me further.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take $x_0 = \frac12(e_1 + e_2)$, then $\langle e_1-x_0,x_0\rangle=\langle e_2-x_0,x_0\rangle=0$.

Comment: We can even set $x_0 = 1/n \sum_{j = 1}^n e_j$. Then $\langle e_j - x_0, x_0\rangle = 0$ for all $j = 1,\ldots, n$. Thus, $S$ can contain arbitrarily many $e_j$ (but not infinitely many).

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- I think 'basis' means 'orthonormal basis'.
- For $x \in S$, we get $\langle x, x_0\rangle > \langle x_0, x_0\rangle/\sqrt{2}$.
- Parseval's identity.

Comment: Thank you! If I follow your hints assuming two indices $m,n$ such that $e_m,e_n\in S$, $\langle x_0,x_0\rangle=\sum_{n\geq1}|\langle x_0,e_n\rangle|^2>2\cdot\frac12\langle x_0,x_0\rangle ^2=\langle x_0,x_0\rangle^2$. The square is inconvenient and it seems difficult to say something from here. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You have a square missing on the very left.

Comment: The theorem reads $\langle x,x\rangle=\|x\|^2=\sum_{n\geq1}|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2$ when $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis, right?

Comment: Oh, now I see my error. With my approach, we get $\|x_0\| < 1$ if $S$ contains more than one basis element.